# PDF versus epub versus mobi files

Tags: pdf, ebook, epub, publishing, mobi

What are the differences between PDF versus epub versus mobi files, in terms of supported functionality, and what software supports such functions and how? I ask because I am interested in publishing an e-book and want to be able to produce the best quality and most usable file possible. Thanks.

Comment: Super User is not a research service. PDF is fundamentally different from the others in that it comes with a fixed page layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of functionality that is specific to ebooks PDF, epub and mobi are all about the same. PDF readers are installed on more computers than ebook readers that support other formats. PDF files are about twice as large as either epub or mobi files, so they take about twice as much space on an ebook reader device. Even so, epub and mobi ebooks can have the same quality as larger PDF ebooks. epub has the advantage over PDF and mobi of being a more open format, so epub files are easier to edit using free open source software than the other two formats.